# How do I make an identity primary key in datamodeler in logical or relational model?

Tags: oracle, identity, ddl

To the primary key that I create there is no option to make it identity, there is only to put the data type, origin, primary key, but there is no option to make identity or I have to add it manually when generating the DDL

Answer (score 0):

If you double click on the column you should be able to set these (I'm on DM 20.3)

[image]